# Time invariance from convolution integral

Tags: convolution, linear-systems

[image: as in given image, I calculated outputs of shifted inputs by convolution]
I wanted to prove, time invariance property of system by convolution integral(i.e equal time shift in input result in equal shift in output) but as calculation shown in figure, I got unexpected result, so what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your delayed input is $\hat{x}(t)=x(t-\alpha)$, then $\hat{x}(t-\tau)=x(t-\tau-\alpha)$, and not $x(t-\tau+\alpha)$. From here everything will work out as expected.